# Circle Embedded in Square Distances

Tags: geometry, circles

In the following situation I know how to find the `red` distance as `(diagonal - diamater) / 2` however I'm not sure how to find the `yellow` and `green` distances.

[image]

Comment: Well shouldn't it be easy using Pythagoras, where the yellow side and green side are equal?

Comment: Are they equal in this case though when the red line is part of the diagonal of the square?

Comment: Yes :) does that solve your question?

Comment: @mankee: Yes, because the red/yellow angle is $45^\circ$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are equal, if red is $r$ then green\yellow is $r/\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 1):

In the above diagram:

Construct a square, such that the diagonal (as shown by the red line) connects the outside square and the circle in the shortest length...

Now, we can see that the green and yellow lines are equal (sides of a square)... Let the red line $= red$, Therefore the green and yellow line = $\frac{red}{\sqrt2}$

---

To answer this in terms of the radius, $r$:

- Side length of square = $2r$
- Diagonal length = $2r\sqrt2$
- red section = $\frac{1}{2}$diagonal - $r$ $= r\sqrt2 - r$

Therefore Green/Yellow section = $\frac{r\sqrt2 - r}{\sqrt2}$

$$=r - \frac{r}{\sqrt2}$$
$$=r - \frac{r\sqrt2}{2}$$